# windows phone app certification process error

Tags: windows-phone-7

Content that is offensive in any country/region to
which your application is targeted is not allowed.
Content may be considered offensive in certain
countries/regions because of local laws or cultural
norms. Examples of potentially offensive content
in certain countries/regions include, but are not
limited to the following:

- Suggestive poses
- Religious references
- Alcohol references
- Simulated or actual gambling

Countries/regions for which one or more parts of
3.10 may apply include the following:

Group 1: China

Group 2: Malaysia, Indonesia

================================================================

Comments: The application prominently features sensitive content sources and includes countries listed in Group 1 within
Application Certification Requirement 3.10 in its targeted distribution.

=================================================================

How to resolve such error during windows phone app certification?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error (unless you are not targeting these countries/regions and are not featuring sensitive content)

Remove the sensitive content or do not target these countries/regions.

Answer (score 0):

apparently user commenting possibility - or any interaction going to happen between users - can result in ms testing house deciding it has sensitive content..